# AWS JAVA LAMBDA on Cloudformation

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation

I am trying to create an empty Lambda via CF and I always see this error:  Properties validation failed for resource ldocarchiverLambda with message: #/Code: expected type: JSONObject, found: String

My Lambda looks this way, what is wrong here?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4h0VX.png)

Comment: Please don't post images of code. It's trivial to copy/paste that into the question itself. See the reason here that you will get downvoted for posting images of code: http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Answer (score 0):

When using CloudFormation, please take the time to look at [the documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-lambda-function-code.html).

The structure you provide to `Code` looks like the following:

> **JSON**
>
> ```
> {
>   "ImageUri" : String,
>   "S3Bucket" : String,
>   "S3Key" : String,
>   "S3ObjectVersion" : String,
>   "ZipFile" : String
> }
> ```
>
> **YAML**
>
> ```
>   ImageUri: String
>   S3Bucket: String
>   S3Key: String
>   S3ObjectVersion: String
>   ZipFile: String
> ```

You don't provide a direct path to a local file. In your case you need to use the `ZipFile` property.

Comment: Hi. Zipfile option is not working with Java.

Comment: @Seba OK? So what isn't  working **exactly**? What is the error message or unexpected behavior you get? If  you want help on here you need to provide enough details for someone to help.

Comment: I am just telling that ZipFile property is not working with Java but working for example with Node. There are 2 ways to ref a code: 1. s3 bucket 2. zipfile and inline reference. I was trying to do it this way: Code: ../../target/file.jar. But when I am doing this way, there is an error -Code: expected type: JSONObject, found: String

Comment: That error has nothing to do with Java vs Node, and everything to do with the way you've formatted the CloudFormation template file. If you posted the actual error message, along with the file that is giving you the error now, someone might be able to help.

Answer (score -1):

`Code` Property cannot be string. Try:

```yaml
      Code:
        S3Bucket: my-bucket
        S3Key: function.zip
```

Comment: I don't want to use S3, is there another method? Also this syntax won't work with Java: Code:
        ZipFile:

Comment: No, there is no another way, just upload your function to s3 before deploying cloudformation

Comment: Using S3 is not a requirement.